# C++ - Another way to use loops

Tags: c++

Are there some other way to type this code?

I want it to be more clear.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string x;
    for (x; x != "EXIT";){
        cin >> x;
        cin.ignore();
        if (x == "EXIT"){
            return EXIT_SUCCESS;
        }
    }
}
```

*The code is supposed to close when you type "EXIT" in the console.*

I found it pretty hard to find the right answers on Google so I decided to ask you guys.
Since I know that Stackoverflow isn't noob-friendly at all I did hesitate to make a question here.

Comment: Without a loop, yes - using recursion. Without a condition(al), no.

Comment: make a function to do it! It will be alot more pretty and readable.

Comment: BTW, your first `x` in the for is useless.

Comment: _"I am new to pointers and such."_ I can't spot a single pointer in your example, and that's good so.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ There's a conceptual one, you just don't see it :)

Comment: @jrok If you mean the `const char*` literal, I've well been spotting it, but that doesn't count ;-) ...

Comment: You can even use `goto` just for the lulz - `int main() { std::string input; repeat: std::cin >> input; if (input != "EXIT") goto repeat; return EXIT_SUCCESS; }` - Sane people don't recommend, but it's an alternative.

Comment: there are no bad questions...

Comment: @RichardHodges Along the policies of SO, there well are _bad questions_, and usually we're going to sort them out and close/delete them.

Comment: @Richard Hodges, It seems like every question that can help a new programmer gets down/close voted.

Comment: @Oscar don't be sorry, and keep asking - it's the only way to learn. The moderators do their job which is to try to keep the site clean and easy to search. Don't take their comments personally - this is the internet, words often seem unkind when they are not meant that way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to test `if (x == "EXIT")` if you're then also going to test `x != "EXIT"`.  Just do:

```
int main(){
    string x;
    while (x != "EXIT"){
        cin >> x;
        cin.ignore();
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

or, with a(n empty) `for` loop:

```
int main() {
    for (string x; x != "EXIT"; (cin >> x).ignore()) ;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Are there some other way I can do it?

Answer (score 2):

Without a loop? **Yes** - You can write a recursive function.

Without a condition(al)? **No**.

Answer (score 2):

While what you have works, some might say a loop that is cleaner might be the following:

```
while (true)
{
    cin >> x;
    if (x == "EXIT")
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This gets rid of the extra condition in the for loop.  If you want to do it without a loop at all you could write a function that uses recursion.

```
int func() {
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    if (x == "EXIT")
        return EXIT_SUCCESS
    return func();
}
```

Comment: you forgot the `goto` variant :-)

Comment: ...knew I forgot something

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a cleaner way to present the same functionality, you could try the following:

```
int main()
{
    string x;
    while(x != "EXIT")
    {
        cin >> x;
        cin.ignore();
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```